# How to modify a 3rd party widget using CSS/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, widget

I have a third party JavaScript widget I am using that I wish to modify the style of, but when I try to put the basic code in my style.css file, it doesn't apply the changes I want to the widget. How can I modify the style on a third party widget using CSS/JavaScript?

The widget code looks like this:

```
(function(d, w, c) {
    w.ID = 'xxx';
    var s = d.createElement('script');
    w[c] = w[c] || function() {
        (w[c].q = w[c].q || []).push(arguments);
    };
    s.async = true;
    s.src = 'widget.js';
    if (d.head) d.head.appendChild(s);
})(document, window, 'Widget');
```

and the CSS I am using to try to modify looks like this:

```
.logo {
    color: #666666 !important;
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Fixed and added. I want to change the logo colors of the CSS widget to match my website better.

Comment: have you tried to target the element of the widget by document.getElementById("element").attr("style", " color: #666666 !important; background-color: #ffffff !important; "); 
?

Comment: Is the widget embedded in a <iframe> ? If so and if it is cross domain, you will not be able to modify the widget CSS, except if your domain is CORS authorized.

Comment: I don't think it is in an iframe and I have just tried to target the element using that JavaScript but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Does anyone have an answer for me? The suggested above does not work.